# Dating a divorcee

Tags: divorce, shidduchim-dating

I'm considering dating a (Jewish) person who was previously legally married to a non-Jew. The person had a secular wedding and a secular divorce. Are there halakhic issues here (independent of any interpersonal concerns particular to my situation)?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question might be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: If you're a kohen it's a problem.